# Unable to call DataSnapshot although declared correctly within ValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement FirebaseDatabase into my Project, but unfortunately I can't use the `DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot`. When I call `mDataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class)` it says "cannot resolve symbol `'mDataSnapshot`".

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren());
            Message message = mDataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
        }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, it's just a syntax issue with your for: for(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Message message = mDataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class); }

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the line that contains the `for`, as it now ends the code block for that loop prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at your for loop's line.

Replace `for(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren());` by `for(DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot  : dataSnapshot.getChildren())`.

It will work.